# Using the SUM of all the values as a condition in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, identity-column

Below is the replica of the table I have created, my goal is to make the username DISTINCT so that the username won't be duplicated, then I want to get the TOTAL or the SUM of value that each person has. For example, on the first row Bob has 2 value, and on the second row, he has another value which is 6 and so on... If you add all the value that Bob has, you would get 25.

```
id     |    username   |  value |   
1              Bob            2       
2              Chris          4
3              Bob            6
4              Bob            12
5              Chris          1
6              Bob            5
7              Viktoriya      8
```

The result I am looking for is something like this:

```
username  |  value
Bob       |   25
Chris     |   5
Viktoriya |   8
```

I achieve this by using this formula:

```
SELECT username, SUM(value) AS value
FROM my_table
GROUP BY username
```

But how about if I want to create a conditioned, lets say, I only want to return the value which is higher than 5 only? I have tried doing the following line below, but did not work.

```
SELECT username, SUM(value) AS value
FROM my_table
GROUP BY username
value >= 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `HAVING` to filter result from aggregate

```
GROUP BY ...
HAVING SUM(value) > 5
```

Comment: Just one quick question, lets say I want the value to be between 5 and 10. How would I achieve it?

Comment: use `HAVING SUM(value) between 5 and 10`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT username, SUM(value) AS value
    FROM my_table
    GROUP BY username
    having SUM(value) >= 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try following:

```
SELECT username, SUM(value) AS value
    FROM my_table
    GROUP BY username HAVING SUM(value) > 5
```

The query will return sum for each username and check that sum is greater than 5 then only return it in output.

Answer (score 0):

Try like below,

```
SELECT username, SUM(value) AS value FROM my_table WHERE value >= 5 GROUP BY username
```